# What does "Size in TCHARs" means?

Tags: c, winapi

In the documentation for [LVCOLUMN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), It says:

[image]

What does "Size in TCHARs" means? Is it `sizeof()` or `strlen()`?

Comment: It means `sizeof(char)`. `TCHAR` is typrdefed `char` -- `typedef char TCHAR;`

Comment: @haccks: `TCHAR` is hardly ever a typedef for `char`. Unless you are working on an application that needs to support Windows 95, `TCHAR` is usually a `wchar_t` (or `unsigned short`).

Comment: @IInspectable; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx

Comment: @haccks: *"Applies to: Outlook"* Also under Remarks: *"For Unicode platforms, TCHAR is defined as synonymous with the WCHAR type."*

Comment: @IInspectable; You said: *`TCHAR` is hardly ever a typedef for `char`*.

Comment: @haccks: My memory is not the best, but I recall having said that, about half an hour ago. Not sure what you're trying to get at. The only non-Unicode platforms are 16-bit Windows, and Windows 95/98/ME. Microsoft offers the *Microsoft Unicode Layer for Windows* for all Win9x editions, so not even those can be called non-Unicode. In essence, you are hardly ever targeting a non-Unicode platform. Consequently, `TCHAR` is hardly ever a typedef for `char`.

Comment: This documentation is very poor. It should say **length** rather than **size**. It is the length of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we all know that `char` is 8-bit, and `wchar_t` is 16-bit. (This isn't always true, but it is on Windows with Microsoft compilers.)

Many (nearly all) of the Windows APIs are implemented under the hood in two versions: one supports Unicode (multi-byte characters) and the other supports 8-bit national character sets. These two functions actually have slightly different names -- typically the 8-bit one ends in "A" and the 16-bit one ends in "W" -- but your code typically doesn't reference either. The function your code calls has no ending letter, and in the `<windows.h>` there's a `#define` which points the symbol at the appropriate function name depending on whether the `UNICODE` symbols is defined. When you declare your strings, you can declare them as type `TCHAR` -- which is `#define`d to be either `char` or `wchar_t` of those depending on whether the symbol `UNICODE` is defined or not.

The original purpose for this was to allow developers to offer two versions of their software, one which is unicode-compliant and calls the unicode APIs, and one which is not and just calls the 8-bit APIs, *and build them from the same source code.* This was important in the days when some widely-installed versions of Windows did not support the Unicode versions. [However, now nearly the entire installed base of Windows is Unicode-compliant, so you should be using the Unicode versions (wide character) everywhere.]

So, size in `TCHAR`s is the same as `strlen()` (or sometimes `strlen()+1`, check the docs) if you're working with only 8-bit, but it's `wcslen()` (or `wcslen()+1`) if you're using wide characters (unicode). In service to their "text unification" project Microsoft introduced `_tcslen()` which maps to the appropriate string length function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78zh94ax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Almost. "Size" doesn't necessarily have to mean the same as `strlen()`; it can be `strlen() + 1` or even the `N` in `TCHAR x[N]` if they want a buffer size. The documentation is usually good at stating which they want (in the case of `strlen() + 1`, the documentation is usually good at saying whether the size should include the terminating null).

Comment: Note that best practice for new projects is to always use the wide character version, i.e., in this case `wcslen`, etc., rather than trying to support both narrow and wide character builds.

Comment: Are you sure that "Size in TCHARs" does not include the terminating NULL character?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the windows api and TCHAR strings, it's neither. You should use `_tcslen` to get the length of the string.

As the others have said, TCHAR is an attempt to abstract over single and double width character strings. `cch` is `count of characters`.

Comment: I disagree; in most cases, you should use `wcslen`.  That way, if you ever accidentally change the build configuration to multibyte you will get a compile error.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The whole point of using `TCHAR` is to write code that compiles correctly with `char` or `WCHAR` types. Using `wcslen` would break that.

Comment: @CareyGregory: but writing code that compiles correctly for both Unicode and multibyte is almost never the right thing to do.  New code should be Unicode-only, and legacy multibyte code should either be left alone or ported to Unicode.  (There are of course some edge cases.  You might, for example, have a library that is shared between multiple projects, only some of which have been ported to Unicode.)

Comment: @CareyGregory: note also that in this particular case, the only reason `TCHAR` is involved is that the Windows API headers use it.  There's nothing in the question to suggest that the OP actually wants his code to run in both modes.

Comment: Be that as it may, the Windows headers still use it and the documentation still refers to it, so anyone coding to the Windows platform needs to understand what it is, why it exists, and how to work with it. I have two products I support that use it. Granted, the non-UNICODE versions aren't built and sold anymore, but mixing `wcslen` in with the existing `_tcslen` would just make an ugly mess, and refactoring a million lines of code just to get rid of `TCHAR` is a project that will never be approved in my lifetime. I'd say if you inherited `TCHAR` code then be consistent and stick with it.

Comment: @CareyGregory: yes, I agree that legacy TCHAR code should usually be maintained as-is.  I'd consider that another edge case. :-)  It might be advisable to put in an `#error` directive somewhere that triggers if the project is accidentally built in multibyte mode, unless you're actively testing both modes on a regular basis.